# Firebase + Node: Updating two refs results in 304 errors

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

What I have is a function that resets a ref when called. It works when updating only one ref.

This is the code for that part of the function:

```
if (streakVal !== 0) {
   //reset
   const uid = item.child('uid').val();
   ref.child(uid).update({ streak: 0 }).catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send(err);
   });
}
```

I also want to update another ref in a different part of the database. I've included it in the same function, as the only difference is the ref location. The part then looks like this:

```
if (streakVal !== 0) {
    //reset
    const uid = item.child('uid').val();

    ref.child(uid).update({ streak: 0 }).then(() => {
        boardRef.child(uid).update({ score: 0 }).catch(err => {
           res.status(500).send(err);
        });
    }).catch(err => {
       res.status(500).send(err);
    });
}
```

The first snippet works. However, the second results in the error `Function execution took 800 ms, finished with status code: 304` I'm wondering why this is and how to fix it. Maybe I'm not structuring it correctly as I'm new to Node. I'm sure that's the correct path to both refs. Here is the full function:

```
export const resetStreak = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const ref = db.ref('users');
  const boardRef = db.ref('streakLeaderboard');

  ref.once('value').then(snap => {
    snap.forEach(item => {
        const streakVal = item.child('streak').val();
        const lastQuestTimestamp = item.child('lastQuest').val();

        const today = new Date();
        const d = new Date(lastQuestTimestamp);

        if (sameDay(today, d) === false) {
          if (streakVal !== 0) {
           //reset
           const uid = item.child('uid').val();

           ref.child(uid).update({ streak: 0 }).then(() => {
            boardRef.child(uid).update({ score: 0 }).catch(err => {
              res.status(500).send(err);
            });
           }).catch(err => {
             res.status(500).send(err);
           });
          }
        }
    })

  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return your `Promise` in your HTTPS functions ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions#how_promises_work_with_functions)). Your code should become:

```
export const resetStreak = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const ref = db.ref('users');
  const boardRef = db.ref('streakLeaderboard');

  return ref.once('value').then(snap => {
    const promises = []
    snap.forEach(item => {
      const streakVal = item.child('streak').val();
      const lastQuestTimestamp = item.child('lastQuest').val();

      const today = new Date();
      const d = new Date(lastQuestTimestamp);

      if (sameDay(today, d) === false) {
        if (streakVal !== 0) {
         //reset
         const uid = item.child('uid').val();

         promises.push(ref.child(uid).update({ streak: 0 }).then(() => {
           return boardRef.child(uid).update({ score: 0 });
         }));
        }
      }
    })
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }).then(() => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  });
```

Comment: Works perfectly, still gives me a 304 error though strangely :/

Comment: @sinio I forgot to send a 200 on success. I edited the answer to include the 200.